# How to convert string month and year into complete date?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am getting `month` and `year` in string format from date picker, how can I convert it to complete date using any date formatter?

Comment: we need to see more code, it depends of how they look like...

Comment: What you mean by complete date ? In that case what should be the day (dd) ?

Comment: @MidhunMP : Complete date means something like "19th Feb 2016".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                try{
                  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
                  String dt = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + String.valueOf(year);
                  Date d = sdf.parse(dt);
                  log.d(d);
                }catch(ParseException ex){}
            }
        };
```

Comment: I am hiding day from date on date set because I don't want to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse a `string` into a `date`, therefore you need the format that associates the String and a date:

Use a dateformat to convert the string into a date:

### Example:

```
String startDateString = "Feb 2007"; //this is the var comming from the datepicker
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
Date startDate;
try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
            String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
            System.out.println(newDateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I am not having day just have month and year ex: "Feb 2016".

Comment: then you can by default asume that it is always the 1st date of that, and parse it to a date

Comment: Yea, that can work, I can do that when I am picking up date from datepicker but that's not an ideal solution.
What if I want to convert it to default date format, I might give you error on parsing for different date formats. 
What do you think?

Comment: thanks for suggestion. 
I am doing it same but after parsing to  ' startDate = df.parse(startDateString); '
I am getting milliseconds from it 'strarDate.getTime()' and then converting to new Date().